# Output voltage from L298N

Tags: pwm, duty-cycle, l298, motordriver

Is it normal to have a higher output voltage than expected from an L298N driver?

I have read that there are voltage drops and it is usual to have lower output voltages, not higher ones. If it is a PWM signal with 90% duty cycle, the output voltage is 4.2V for a 6V supply, and that is what I was expecting (90% x 6V = 5.4V but including the voltage drops from an L298N driver 4.2V is ok), but if the duty cycle is lower, 50%, the output voltage is 3.28V which is higher than 3V maximum that I have expected from a 6V supply.

I have added a schematic: the MCU is a SoC from Cypress, power supply is 6V from the converter and I have measured the voltage between Out1 and Out2 using a multimeter.
Is there any chance to be a wrong measurement because of using a multimeter instead an oscilloscope? Or is this a normal behavior because there is a common ground between the microcontroller and the driver (and in that way the driver uses its voltage supply, but also the an additional voltage from the microcontroller)?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Please provide a schematic of the relevant circuit; to let us see how you are driving the IC and what load you connect it to.

Comment: Also indicate **how** and using **what instrument** to measure the voltage. If you use a multimeter it is not guaranteed that the result is accurate. I would use an **oscilloscope**.

Comment: I have a Dual Axis Metal TT Gear Motor as a load and unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope to measure. I have used a multimeter to measure the difference between Out1 and Out2 from the motor driver

Comment: Ah, the infamous Dual Axis TT gear motor. Is it [this one?](https://electropeak.com/double-axis-1-48-metal-gear-motor). What PWM frequency are you running?

Comment: Yes, this one. It's a 8bit PWM with clock frequency of 50kHz and a period of 100, that gives the motors an input frequency of 500Hz

Comment: how do you measure "output voltage"? We'll really need a schematic that tells us what you connect how and where you observe these voltages, and with which kind of measurement device!

Comment: I added a schematic but I am not sure it is very useful because I couldn't find the PSoC to show the actual wiring. The measurement device is a multimeter and I observe the voltage between Out1 and Out2

Comment: @Anna - Hi, As you see, I have undeleted this question, after you deleted it and [asked the same question again](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574372/out1-out2-voltage-for-l298n-driver). (I see you have now deleted *that* one.) Please do *not* ask the same question multiple times. That is considered to be "noise" and is not allowed. If you do not get an answer to your question, there is [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) advice from the [help]. Thanks.